# Endpoint Details For Google Play Console Main Store Listing

Tags: google-play, base64, web-crawler, google-play-console

In google-play-console, I'm trying to find main-store-listing details(https://doc.siberiancms.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Screenshot-2020-10-21-at-16.08.21.png) with endpoint from network tab but I couldn't find it.

I found an endpoint like https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/developers/apps/storelistings/main:startupData but it returns base64 encoded data and when I decode it, it contains some unknown characters.

Example Response:

```
{"1":{"1":"type.googleapis.com/play.console.apps.api.storelistings.MainStoreListingPageStartupDataResponse","2":"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"}}
```

I need data like:

```
locale, title, subtitle, description, screenshots, icon...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a base64 encoded **protobuf** data. you can decode it from https://protogen.marcgravell.com easily.